# How do I show a custom modal in a freemarker list?

Tags: html, freemarker, ktor

I have a Ktor server and I am showing a few webpages with freemarker templates. On one page I have a table. Each row contains a button that the user can click. If the user clicks the button then modal should show up with information about that table row.

I can get a modal to show up but the data it shows is always from the first row, no matter which row I select. How can I get the modal to show data about the particular row I click on? I would prefer an answer that does not involve javascript.

```
                        <#list categories as category>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${category.displayName}</td>
                                <td>${category.pathName}</td>
                                <td>${category.priority}</td>
                                <td>${category.uuid}</td>
                                <td>${category.enabled?string('yes', 'no')}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <form method="post" action="/portal/home/categories">
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCategoryModal">
                                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                            Edit
                                        </a>
<#--                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" name="toggleEnabled" value="${category.uuid}">
                                            Toggle
                                        </button>-->
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="editCategoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                                 aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">${category.displayName}</h5>
                                            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </#list>
```

Updated code based on suggestion:

```
                        <#list categories as category>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${category.displayName}</td>
                                <td>${category.pathName}</td>
                                <td>${category.priority}</td>
                                <td>${category.uuid}</td>
                                <td>${category.enabled?string('yes', 'no')}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" href="#" data-toggle="modal"
                                   data-target=".modal[data-id=${category.uuid}]">
                                    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Edit
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <div class="modal fade" data-id="${category.uuid}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                                 aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">${category.displayName}</h5>
                                            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </#list>
```

Example of generated HTML:

Generated Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" data-id="6a8dbcf2-2580-4c81-b4c1-5f2f4762a6d0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Issues </h5>
                                            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Generated Row

```
<tr>
                                <td>Issues </td>
                                <td>/issues</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>6a8dbcf2-2580-4c81-b4c1-5f2f4762a6d0</td>
                                <td>yes</td>
                                <td>
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal[data-id=6a8dbcf2-2580-4c81-b4c1-5f2f4762a6d0]">
                                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                            Edit
                                        </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

For each item in the list, you have a modal element with the same ID so the browser always finds the first one. Since you have `uuid` for each category I suggest using its value for a data attribute to unambiguously identify modals. So the `data-target` attribute of an anchor will be the following:

```
data-target=".modal[data-id=${category.uuid}]"
```

And the `id` of a modal is replaced by `data-id` attribute:

```
data-id="${category.uuid}"
```

Comment: Now the modal doesn't show at all. I updated the code as you said

Comment: @AdrianLeRoyDevezin could you please share the example of rendered values for `data-target` and `data-id` attributes?

Comment: @AdrianLeRoyDevezin could you please check https://jsfiddle.net/4ugy2ap8/? Does it work for you?

Comment: So @Aleksei Tirman the issue is that only the last one works. It must work inside the <#list> tag

Comment: @AdrianLeRoyDevezin they should have different `uuid` to make it work

Comment: They do. I moved the generated HTML to jsfiddle and it works. It is not working in any of my local browsers though. Only some rows will work.